# Is having a polymorphic table for storing my Image information more efficient than a separate table for each model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Background Information:**

In Laravel 7, I have many Models like ***Product***, ***Variant***, ***User***, ***Container***, and ***Package*** that can have an Image.

**Problem:**

Should I create a polymorphic table called images to store the images for all of the models?

Or is it more efficient to have separate tables to store the images of that specific model?

- For example product_images, variant_images, user_images and etc...

**Notes:**

- The **Product** has approximately 600 records.
- The **Variant** has approximately 200 records.
- The **User** has approximately 10 records.
- The **Container** has approximately 300 records.
- The **Package** has approximately 200 records.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of efficiency. It's more a matter of semantics. How likely is it to have the image metadata diverge depending on the model they relate to? E.g. if you want to add a caption to the image will it apply for every case or will not make sense for e.g. users

Comment: @apokryfos Ahh so you are saying it would make sense to create another table only if I want to add a field that is specific to a model. Correct?

Comment: Well in a more abstract way if the concept of "Product image" is not sufficiently the same as the concept of "User image" then they probably are their own entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of efficiency and flexibility and database architecture it's better to store related data in 1 table, we don't store laptops in a table called `laptops` and mobiles in a table called `mobiles` we store them in `products` table so creating tables for each model to store the images is not the best solution the best solution is to create 1 table to store the images for all the models so the answer is [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

**But let us get back to what I typed earlier:**

> In case of efficiency and flexibility and database architecture it's
>   better to store related data in 1 table

What if we want to store pdf or excel sheet or attach videos to products are we going to create tables for each type of files for example videos table ?

**Umm ... for sure not so how can we handle this ?**

easy, all we have to do is to create only 1 table to store the media/files so we will create a table called `files` for example and store in this table all the images, videos ... etc

**Alright great, now we know the concept how can we achieve that with laravel ?**

First create a migration and a model using the following command:
`php artisan make:model File -m`

in the created migration file make sure to add the right columns as below:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('file'); // to store the location of the file/media
        $table->morphs('fileable');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

then run `php artisan migrate`

now in the `AppServiceProvider` located in `app/Providers` in the `boot` function add the following:

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
    'products'   => 'App\Product',
    'variants'   => 'App\Variant',
    'users'      => 'App\User',
    'containers' => 'App\Container',
    'packages'   => 'App\Package'
]);
```

done!

for more info about the polymorphic relationships checkout this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: So a product will have a full-sized image and a thumbnail. What would be your approach to solve this new obstacle? Do I create a boolean column in the images table called "is_thumbnail"?

Comment: yeah you can do so, or you can add a new column called type that will take values like thumbnail, normal... etc